# Default width of relatively positioned div

Tags: css

If the position of div tag is absolute, by default, its height and width are 0, but if the position is relative, by default the width is 300px, I want a div tag with 0 width and relative position...

Comment: There is no default width for `div` elements whatsoever. Where'd you come up with 300px?

Comment: A 0 width div would be invisible, no?

Comment: don't know what you are trying to do but if you are trying to hide a div use display:none; or visibility:hidden;

Comment: @BoltClock is right. The 300px is coming from the div's container.

Comment: @ExplosionPills No, the thing is I have to place absolutely positioned  many div tags inside it and I want the container div tag's height and width to be adjusted automatically, but by giving width:auto also, it defaults to 300 only...

Comment: @BoltClock, nope its not coming from the div's container, I checked it...

Answer (score 2):

Then just make it:

```
 <div style="position:relative; width:0;"></div>
```

Comment: By giving explicitly width:0 it will not be able to hold it's content div tags...

Comment: @user1461677 Use `overflow:visible` if you must. You have a problem with your CSS elsewhere if `width:auto;height:auto` isn't working.

Comment: No other problem else where, I thoroughly checked it... It just follows the following class: .container1
{
 padding:2px;
 border:1px dotted white;
 position:relative;
 left:10px;
 top:15px;
 height:auto;
 width:auto;
 border:1px solid black;
} Still taking a huge width

Comment: @Hazel Then something inside has the width (if it's not being defined elsewhere). You may need to post a fiddle so we can debug what you're observing.